# Creating disable opacity bootstrap 3?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am using bootstrap 3, with panel i need to create inside body of the panel opacity that user can not click on link, here is my working fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/52VtD/9230/

The problem is that opacity always get full screen i need to be only in panel body?
I need to make that only with css, is that possible?

Here is my code so far

```
<div class="panel panel-primary">
   <div class="panel-heading">
      <h3 class="panel-title">Panel title</h3>
   </div>
   <div class="panel-body">
       <a href="#">I dont want allow user to clikc on this link</a>
   </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.panel-body:before{
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 999;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
}
```

**UPDATE**

I have find out better solution

```
.panel-body{
    opacity: .7;
    pointer-events: none;
}
```

Comment: Note that `pointer-events` are not supported in IE10 and below - http://caniuse.com/#feat=pointer-events

Comment: Why do you want an unclickable link in the first place?

Comment: i want not just link, everything inside to be not clickable

Answer (score 0):

The way I've done this in the past is by making the container (i.e. the thing you want to lay your transparent cover over) have `position:relative` then create a `div` within that container with `height:100%` and `position:absolute`. This then covers the whole of the parent div. Here's a full working example.

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
    <p>Ahoy, I'm some text</p>
    <p><a href="#">And I'm a link!</a></p>
    <img src="http://placehold.it/100" alt="I'm an image"/>

    <div class="cover"></div>

</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.container{
    position:relative;
    border:2px solid #663399;
    padding:5px;
}
.cover {
    background-color: #fff;
    height: 100%;
    left: 0;
    opacity: 0.9;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(opacity=90); /*Yay for old IE support...*/
}
```

**[jsFiddle working example](http://jsfiddle.net/gesqr8v2/)**

By just using a semi transparent div covering the elements within them instantly makes them non-clickable, so no need to mess around with `pointer-events`, but it does require you have a relatively positioned container div.

Comment: Is it possible to add this with css?

Comment: That is just CSS. If you are talking about dynamically adding it to the page or toggling it on or off then no, you need JavaScript for something like that, but that applies to what you've already written anyway.